# Angularjs service: when should we use isArray vs params

Tags: angularjs, service, return-value

Can someone explain when should we use `isArray vs params` in Angular services?
Assuming in api the return value is `ArrayList<MyCustomeCalss>`

In my service I have

```
 angular.module('MyApp').factory('MyService', ['$resource', 'URLService', function ($resource, URL) {
    return $resource("",null,
    {
        'geresult': {
            method: 'POST',
            url: URL.get('result'),
            //isArray: true  when to use??
            //params: {}     when to use??
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood something...but don't get it why ***vs***?

***isArray*** is just says you that you'll get an array throughout this resource and an array will be returned instantly for you to be able to iterate over it and then it will be populated by your data, so you can use it as an array after you just call a resource.

quote from documentation:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view.

***params*** is just pre-bounded  params for your POST request. You can read [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2433-Using-RESTful-Controllers-In-An-AngularJS-Resource.htm) for better understanding

Comment: I changed my code to return Array<Object> and I only have isArray: true when I debug using chrome once it goes to isArray:true  then stops without showing anything. If I set params:{} it shows `error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter`

Comment: try to see what data exactly goes over the network for you request using some traffic analyzer such as wireshark. The err you described is shown when the data format you receive mismatch the data format angular expects. When you set params do you remove isArray?

Comment: yes I do :( originally I returned Map and I got it in the UI but it was like `{"1234":["John","123","7000 Park St"]}` and I dont know how to access it in html. because it does have key like "id":"1234"

Comment: the `$scope.output is Array[0]
$promise: Object
$resolved: false
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0] `